How to reach inner button inside a inner open shadow root with selenium
a webpage has this HTML
<custom-tag1 class data-component-key="..." ...>
 #shadow-root (open)
  <div class="...">
    <custom-tag2 ...>
     #shadow-root (open)
     <button class="button-download" style="background: transparent; border: 0;">
     </button>
    </custom-tag2>
  </div>
</custom-tag1>

I can reach the first shadow root by doing
outer_host = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("custom-tag1")
outer_shadow_root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", outer_host)

but then I can't repeat the process.   The outer_shadow_root is a ShadowRoot class.
It has a find_element method, but I fail to locate custom-tag2
No invocation of the find_element by any locator works
Any ideas?

Native shadow locator supports only few locator strategies (ID, NAME, CLASS_NAME and CSS_SELECTOR). Go with CSS Selector like below is working for me

custom_tag_1_root = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'custom-tag1').shadow_root
custom_tag_2_root = custom_tag_1_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'custom-tag2').shadow_root
download = custom_tag_2_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.button-download')
download.click()

if difficult to find CSS Selector and only Xpath can be constructed then go with third party libraries to handle shadow dom.
